# The Juju link in the top bar is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

I just started playing around with the links at the top, seeing how they mirrored the Ubuntu.com links, and I noticed something.

The Juju link appears to be outdated. The one on AU goes to `http://juju.ubuntu.com/`, while the one on the Ubuntu site goes to `https://jujucharms.com/`. The link here on AU is also dead.

While I was writing this question, I also noticed that our top bar is missing the Partners link. Is this something worthy of addressing?

Answer (score 4):

Fixed, the Juju link is pointing to the correct address now.